# Encountered a problem while configuring CentOS in Docker

Tags: docker, ssh, dockerfile

I configured CentOS using a Dockerfile, where I intended to utilize **CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]** to enable SSH service to start automatically every time the container boots up. However, it **gets stuck** after I execute docker run.
**This is my dockerfile.**

```
FROM centos:7.9.2009
 
# 安装openssh-server和sudo软件包，并且将sshd的UsePAM参数设置成no  
RUN yum install -y openssh-server sudo
RUN sed -i 's/UsePAM yes/UsePAM no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#安装openssh-clients
RUN yum install -y openssh-clients
#安装epel-release
RUN yum install -y epel-release
#安装net-tools
RUN yum install -y net-tools
#安装vim
RUN yum install -y vim


# # 添加测试用户root，密码，并且将此用户添加到sudoers里  
RUN echo "root:310013" | chpasswd
RUN echo "root   ALL=(ALL)       ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
RUN ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 256 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
RUN ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -b 256 -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# 启动sshd服务并且暴露22端口  
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
EXPOSE 22

# 每次开机自启动sshd都会卡死，为什么？
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]

ADD jdk-8u401-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/
RUN mv /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_401 /usr/local/jdk1.8
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/local/jdk1.8
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

ADD hadoop-3.3.6-src.tar.gz /usr/local
RUN mv /usr/local/hadoop-3.3.6-src /usr/local/hadoop
ENV HADOOP_HOME /usr/local/hadoop
ENV PATH $HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

[Problem's Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHqt5.png)

I tried removing this line in the Dockerfile and manually executing the /usr/sbin/sshd -d command inside the container, and found no issues.

Comment: In general, ssh server isn't needed within docker containers

Comment: (Is it actually a good idea to hard-code a root password like that, where `docker history` on the image will show it in plain text?  Will it be a problem if the ssh host key changes unpredictably when the image is rebuilt, or if the private key can be easily extracted from the image?)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs while running SSH server (sshd) with certain configurations that are not compatible with CentOS / Red Hat Enterprise Linux, here it is the `UsePAM no` directive. A workaround would be to add a step in your Dockerfile, before running `sshd`, to comment this directive in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Example:

```bash
# 每次开机自启动sshd都会卡死，为什么？
RUN sed -i 's/^UsePAM no$/#UsePAM no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```